# Backward compatibility issue with iOS Segue Data transfer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue, compatibility

I have discovered a curious issue with some, but not all older hardware running iOS 9.3.5    I would really appreciate any thoughts regarding why this happens. I know I could work around the problem with a singleton global, but this seems so ugly.

In the bad cases, data transfer via a segue does not arrive in the new view controller, whereas with other old hardware running 9.3.5 and all newer hardware everything works as expected.

In brief, I have an App which uses a Master/Detail design which I built up with Interface Builder (not the standard template). The main ViewController includes a UITableView and also uses both the  STCollapse and the MMDrawerSideSlide libraries. Selecting a table row generates a segue in which the prepareForSegue loads some items into properties of the DetailViewController. An NSString property always arrives OK, but in some old hardware (see below) the NSIndexPath of the selected row is correctly moved into the detail’s property in the prepareForSegue in the main VC, but does not arrive in the DetailViewController and the property is NIL when the detail’s viewDidLoad executes.

Table of Value by hardware and iOS version of NSIndexPath in DetailViewController

```
iPad 2       9.3.5   nil
iPad Air     9.3.5   nil
iPad Air2    9.3.5   correct
iPhone 5     9.3.5   nil
iPhone 5s    9.3.5   correct
iPhone 6     9.3.5   correct
all devices  10.x    correct
```

Code Snippets

Main ViewController.m

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toDetail" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toDetail"])
    {
        DetailViewController *detailVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        detailVC.selectedIndex = self.selectedIndexPath;
        detailVC.searchName = _theName;
    }
}


DetailViewController.h
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSIndexPath * selectedIndex;
@property (nonatomic, weak)NSString * searchName;



DetailViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad {       //In new hardware _selectedIndex is OK, in some old hardware, is nil,  _searchName is always OK!
    [super viewDidLoad];
    Kings *flatkings = [Kings sharedKings];
    self.flatSequenceNumber = (int)[flatkings getFlatIndexFromTablePath:_selectedIndex];
    [self drawTheView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The lifetime qualifiers for `selectedIndex` and `searchName` should be `copy`, not `weak`. There's no reason for two view controllers to share a reference to the same string. Even if you wanted to share the references, you should use `strong`, not `weak`, since there's no potential retain cycle.

Apple's [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) is a great resource for getting a better understanding of lifetime qualifiers.

Comment: Good Point! Should be a copy. However, I don't see how the indexPath becomes nil with certain hardware, and not others while the NSString is always passed correctly.  I have temporized by adding a global reference for the indexPath, but would like to understand the possible underlying failure mechanism(s).

Comment: You've basically written a bug in your code that happens to work by luck in some versions of the SDK.

Comment: Not very satisfying but probably true ;)